# How to style Text wrap in React Native

Tags: react-native, word-wrap, react-native-stylesheet

I have text like below,

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx (xxxxxxxx)

and I have code like this:

```
<View
    style={{
        width: '77%',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
    }}>
    <Text
        style={[
            styles.address,
            {
                textAlign: 'right',
                flexWrap: 'wrap',
            },
        ]}
        selectable={true}>
        {addressName[0]}
    </Text>
    {addressName[1] && (
        <Text
            style={[
                styles.address,
                {
                    textAlign: 'right',
                    flexWrap: 'nowrap',
                },
            ]}
            selectable={true}>
            {'(' + addressName[1]}
        </Text>
    )}
</View>
```

The current result while text is too long,

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxx
(xxxxxxx)
```

but I want it to be

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxx (xxxxxxx)
```

and I dont want

```
xxxxxxxxxxx
xxxx (xxxxx
xx)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use nested `Text` components, something like this:

```
const addressName = ['xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxx']

return (
  <View
      style={{
          width: '70%',
      }}>
      <Text>
        {addressName[0]}
        {addressName[1] &&
          <Text>
              {' (' + addressName[1] + ')'}
          </Text>
        }
      </Text>
  </View>
)
```